# Importing shap occurs error even though updating all libraries

Tags: python, numba, shap

When I import `shap`, I get error as below.

I tried to reinstall `shap` and update `conda`, `numpy`, `numba`, `llvmlite`.

Interesting thing is that `llvmlite` version is 0.38.0 in jupyter notebook but the error occurs same as below.

Unexpected exception formatting exception. Falling back to standard exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3369, in run_code
    ----------
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_22980\3975714860.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    import shap
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._explanation import Explanation, Cohorts
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\_explanation.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils._general import OpChain
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\utils\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._clustering import hclust_ordering, partition_tree, partition_tree_shuffle, delta_minimization_order, hclust
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\utils\_clustering.py", line 4, in <module>
    from numba import jit
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\__init__.py", line 199, in <module>
    _ensure_llvm()
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\__init__.py", line 111, in _ensure_llvm
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Numba requires at least version 0.38.0 of llvmlite.
Installed version is 0.37.0.
Please update llvmlite.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1982, in showtraceback
    'the full traceback.\n']
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1118, in structured_traceback
    return FormattedTB.structured_traceback(
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1012, in structured_traceback
    return VerboseTB.structured_traceback(
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 865, in structured_traceback
    formatted_exception = self.format_exception_as_a_whole(etype, evalue, etb, number_of_lines_of_context,
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 818, in format_exception_as_a_whole
    frames.append(self.format_record(r))
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 736, in format_record
    result += ''.join(_format_traceback_lines(frame_info.lines, Colors, self.has_colors, lvals))
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stack_data\utils.py", line 145, in cached_property_wrapper
    value = obj.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(obj)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stack_data\core.py", line 698, in lines
    pieces = self.included_pieces
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stack_data\utils.py", line 145, in cached_property_wrapper
    value = obj.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(obj)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stack_data\core.py", line 649, in included_pieces
    pos = scope_pieces.index(self.executing_piece)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stack_data\utils.py", line 145, in cached_property_wrapper
    value = obj.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(obj)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stack_data\core.py", line 628, in executing_piece
    return only(
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\executing\executing.py", line 164, in only
    raise NotOneValueFound('Expected one value, found 0')
executing.executing.NotOneValueFound: Expected one value, found 0
```

After I tried to update with "conda update llvmlite".

I got an error as below. What should I have to do?

```
(base) C:\Users\user>conda update llvmlite
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaSSLError: OpenSSL appears to be unavailable on this machine. OpenSSL is required to
download and install packages.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))
```

Comment: This sounds like yet another question related to having multiple python interpreters and thus multiple versions of python libraries (one per interpreter).

Comment: Install openssl

Comment: Thanks all for comment. I just solved problem by reinstalling anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict between `numba` and `llvm` version while importing.

Read the below lines carefully:

```
ImportError: Numba requires at least version 0.38.0 of llvmlite.
Installed version is 0.37.0.
Please update llvmlite.
```

Try:

```
conda list llvmlite
```

or, if needed

```
conda update llvmlite
```

As you claim you already have the correct `llvmlite` in path, I think the shortest path is to do

```
conda deactivate
pip install -U llvmlite
```

Otherwise, search for problems in your `$PATH` / `env` defintions

Comment: # Name----------------Version----------------Build  Channel
llvmlite---------------- 0.38.0----------------py39h23ce68f_0

Above is the result of  "conda list llvmlite"

Comment: As I said already, you may debug path issues forever. Find systemwide llvmlite and update it. Possible solution is in the answer.

Comment: Thanks all for comment. I just solved problem by reinstalling anaconda.